# insert query to have both a select and a value as values

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, sql-insert

I know you can use a select statement to supply all the values, but it wont let me use it to just supply 1 of the values, then use another item to supply the next value.

```
INSERT INTO table
([product code], [product description])
VALUES
(
   (SELECT [code] FROM table GROUP BY [code])
   ,'a description'
)
```

But SQL Server tells me

> Sub query returned more than 1 value

For now I have gotten around it by making that select statement a view and then joined it.
Would be nice to not need a view though.

Comment: remove values...if you want tot select  from another table

Comment: sample input table??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SELECT` statement with `INSERT INTO . . .` statement :

```
INSERT INTO table ([product code], [product description])
     SELECT [code], 'a description'  
     FROM table 
     GROUP BY [code];
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want `INSERT . . . SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO table ([product code], [product description])
    SELECT [code], 'a description'
    FROM table
    GROUP BY [code];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you insert using `VALUES`, you can only insert one row at a time, however, the query

> 'SELECT [code] FROM table GROUP BY [code]'

returns multiple rows hence the query fails. If you want to use `VALUES` to insert you would need to loop through each row in the query and insert separately, however, this is unnecessary and inefficient. As others have already pointed out it is far more efficient to simply use the below:

```
INSERT INTO table ([product code], [product description])
     SELECT [code], 'a description'  
     FROM table 
     GROUP BY [code];
```